# Selecting an element in the same parent as target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assuming I have a set up of:

```
<ul id="cal">
    <li><span>test</span><img /></li>
    <li><span>test</span><img /></li>
    <li><span>test</span><img /></li>
</ul>
```

and in the jQuery:

```
$('#cal li span').hover(function(){
    $("#cal li img").trigger('mouseover');
});
```

I need to trigger mouseover on the #cal li img, but on only the image of the span rather than all of the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify it is linked to your context with:

```
$('#cal li span').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("img").trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: @JoshBoothe That's *absolutely* not efficient to search for siblings via parent node.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to closest `<img>` using `$(this).next()` or with:

```
$("#cal li span").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings("img").trigger("mouseover");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Will this trigger a `:hover` selector in the CSS? I need it to change opacity on the hover, works fine on the image, but it isnt working with the new JS

Comment: @JoshBoothe No, jQuery can't operate with CSS pseudo-classes. You can add `.hover` class to the stylesheet and toggle it on hover to make it work.

Comment: I know the method, i only thought it only worked with selectors like $("p").next(), but next doesn't iterate over the result i see.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cal li span').hover(function(){
    $(this).next("img").trigger('mouseover');
});
```